# Invalid version when updating certificate with certbot

Tags: ubuntu, lets-encrypt, certbot

I have a server with a Let's encrypt certificate installed with certbot. I want to renew it with the following command
`sudo certbot renew --force-renewal`

but I get an error:

```
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Processing /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/mydomain.conf
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Plugins selected: Authenticator standalone, Installer None
Renewing an existing certificate
Attempting to renew cert (mydomain) from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/mydomain.conf produced an unexpected error: Invalid version. The only valid version for X509Req is 0.. Skipping.
All renewal attempts failed. The following certs could not be renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/fullchain.pem (failure)

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

All renewal attempts failed. The following certs could not be renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/fullchain.pem (failure)
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
1 renew failure(s), 0 parse failure(s)
```

I have Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS,Python 3.8.10
What should I do?

Comment: check `X509Req` in `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal/mydomain.conf`?

Comment: here is the contents of the conf file 
# renew_before_expiry = 30 days
version = 0.40.0
archive_dir = /etc/letsencrypt/archive/my domain
cert = /etc/letsencrypt/live/my domain/cert.pem
privkey = /etc/letsencrypt/live/my domain/privkey.pem
chain = /etc/letsencrypt/live/my domain/chain.pem
fullchain = /etc/letsencrypt/live/my domain/fullchain.pem

# Options used in the renewal process
[renewalparams]
account = [my account]
pref_challs = http-01,
authenticator = standalone
server = https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem in Ubuntu 18.04 and it was caused by the pyOpenSSL 23.2.0 version. After downgrading to 23.1.1 it worked again:

```
pip3 install pyOpenSSL==23.1.1
```

Comment: Yes, looks like this bug: https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/9722 and the problem is that although `csr.set_version(0)` is used [since `acme-v1.29.0`](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/commit/dedbdea1d9854761df9ba28d26e368bdd78d72c9), but because since `acme==1.24.0` there is a dependency on `Python >=3.7`, the latest `acme` version which can be installed with Python 3.6 is `acme-1.23.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Today I've got this problem on Debian 10 machine which we do not upgrade. And some time ago it was working, but now I've got same error (Invalid version. The only valid version for X509Req is 0.. Skipping.). I've solved it by simple upgrading certbot:

```
pip3 install -U certbot
```

This helped, `certbot renew` worked well. Now, `pip freeze` shows these relevant packages installed for me:

```
certbot==2.7.4
pyOpenSSL==24.0.0
```

I think using recent version of security libraries is much better then downgrade to old versions.