# ValueError: Invalid version. The only valid version for X509Req is 0

Tags: openssl, certbot

I'm trying to renew the SSL but I got this error:

[SSL Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuRjH.png)

[SSL Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soY86.png)

I already tried `sudo pip3 install pyOpenSSL` and `sudo pip3 install cryptography==40.0.1`, uninstalled it, and installed it again, but it didn't work.

How to solve this?

Comment: Welcome! It would be much easier to read (take that as "you'd get more answers") if you pasted the output as text  into the question (use Code Sample to format it) instead of linking to images .  Also, search engines find your question, which may help others with the same problem.

Comment: Is it: https://serverfault.com/questions/1132420/invalid-version-when-updating-certificate-with-certbot